# Adding manual pieces of code to SP site

Tags: 2007, html, aspx

I want to add a chunk of source code to a specific web page using SPDesigner 2007.
The code consists of 2 parts. Some needs to go in what would normally be the `<head>` section of a web site. The rest just needs to go in the body.

How do I find out where the `<head>` section is? I don't see it in the source for the web page?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an aspx page you are creating, then you need to do a couple things.

First you'll want to go to the style tab in the ribbon and attach the default or custom masterpage.

Then you'll need to add the following just below the registration line:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
//code goes here
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
//html markup goes here
</asp:Content>
```